# install Jupyter extension

Tags: python, installation, jupyter

I want to install check spelling jupyter's extension. 
I followed [this instruction](http://www.simulkade.com/posts/2015-04-07-spell-checking-in-jupyter-notebooks.html) but it required root privileges.
I want to do it on computing cluster so obviously I don't have it. 
Is it a way to install this extension without super user?
In other word can you show me equivalent to pip --user flag?

Answer (score -1):

Would using the newer command helps? The article uses `ipython` command, which is superceded by `jupyter`.

Download the tools using this in the terminal instead:-

```
$ jupyter nbextension install https://bitbucket.org/ipre/calico/downloads/calico-spell-check-1.0.zip
$ jupyter nbextension install https://bitbucket.org/ipre/calico/downloads/calico-document-tools-1.0.zip
$ jupyter nbextension install https://bitbucket.org/ipre/calico/downloads/calico-cell-tools-1.0.zip
```

Then, enable them using:-

```
$ jupyter nbextension enable calico-spell-check
$ jupyter nbextension enable calico-document-tools
$ jupyter nbextension enable calico-cell-tools
```

Comment: Have you tested your solution before posted it? I suppose not. 
[bash] $ jupyter nbextension install https://bitbucket.org/ipre/calico/downloads/calico-spell-check-1.0.zip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  (....) 
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/share/jupyter'

Comment: Hmm... I just did it myself that morning before you asked the question though. Maybe my system is setup differently... I believe I am not root, but my Jupyter may be a local installation that's why... not sure... Anyway, hope you find your solution then.